# How to use array class property in different self-class methods?

Tags: php

I have a class like that :

```
class Calculator 
{
    protected $date;
    protected $capital;
    protected $rate;
    protected $frequency;
    protected $duration;
    protected $charges;
    protected $forcedPayments;
    protected $result_array;
    protected $chargesArray;


public function constantAmortization($date, $capital, $rate, $duration, $frequency, $charges)
 {
        $allPayments = $allInterests = array();
        $amortization = $capital / $duration;
        $interestTotal = 0; $amortizationTotal = 0;
          for($i = 0; $i < $duration; $i++){
              $interest = $capital * ($rate / 100) / $frequency;
              array_push($allInterests,$interest);
              $payment = $amortization + $interest;
              array_push($allPayments,$payment);
              $remaining = $capital - $amortization;
                //calculate totals for table headers output in twig :
                $interestTotal += $interest; $amortizationTotal += $amortization; 
                $inverseCapital = $capital * -1;
                $paymentTotal = $amortizationTotal + $interestTotal;     

              $this->result_array[$i] = result_array(
                          'Date' => $date->format('d/m/y'),
                          'Capital' => $capital,
                          'Rate' => $rate,
                          'Interest' => $interest,
                          'Payment' => $payment,
                          'Amortization' => $amortization,
                          'Remaining' => $remaining,
                          'InterestTotal' => $interestTotal,
                          'AmortizationTotal' => $amortizationTotal,
                          'PaymentTotal' => $paymentTotal,
                          'InverseCapital' => $inverseCapital,
                      );

              $capital = $remaining;
              $months = (12/$frequency). ' months';
              $date->modify($months);
        }
    }
```

So, in this method, based on class properties, the 'array_result' property of a class is filled by values that are outputed later on my front-end.

Below that code I have a method called charges() that make as well different calculations and fill the chargesArray property of a class with values, that are outputed in my front-end too.

Now, I have to improve my functional, so I have to implement something in my charges() method to make value of a charge as percent of capital initial / remaining at each iteration in my constantAmortization() method.

How can I do it? In my thoughts I have to use the result_array property inside my charges() method, to iterate this array, and based on capital and remaining values to make some calculations, but it gives me errors when I'm trying to use/display result_array inside the charges() method. What I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Calc = new Calculator;
$output = Calc::constantAmortization($date, $capital, $rate, $duration, $frequency, $charges);
/* or */
$output = Calc->constantAmortization($date, $capital, $rate, $duration, $frequency, $charges);
```

**Great explanation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php by farzan at ifarzan dot com ¶**

PHP 5 is very very flexible in accessing member variables and member functions. These access methods maybe look unusual and unnecessary at first glance; but they are very useful sometimes; specially when you work with SimpleXML classes and objects. I have posted a similar comment in SimpleXML function reference section, but this one is more comprehensive.

I use the following class as reference for all examples:

```
<?php 
class Foo { 
    public $aMemberVar = 'aMemberVar Member Variable'; 
    public $aFuncName = 'aMemberFunc'; 


    function aMemberFunc() { 
        print 'Inside `aMemberFunc()`'; 
    } 
} 

$foo = new Foo; 
?>
```

You can access member variables in an object using another variable as name:

```
<?php 
$element = 'aMemberVar'; 
print $foo->$element; // prints "aMemberVar Member Variable" 
?>
```

or use functions:

```
<?php 
function getVarName() 
{ return 'aMemberVar'; } 

print $foo->{getVarName()}; // prints "aMemberVar Member Variable" 
?>
```

Important Note: You must surround function name with { and } or PHP would think you are calling a member function of object "foo".

you can use a constant or literal as well:

```
<?php 
define(MY_CONSTANT, 'aMemberVar'); 
print $foo->{MY_CONSTANT}; // Prints "aMemberVar Member Variable" 
print $foo->{'aMemberVar'}; // Prints "aMemberVar Member Variable" 
?>
```

You can use members of other objects as well:

```
<?php 
print $foo->{$otherObj->var}; 
print $foo->{$otherObj->func()}; 
?>
```

You can use mathods above to access member functions as well:

```
<?php 
print $foo->{'aMemberFunc'}(); // Prints "Inside `aMemberFunc()`" 
print $foo->{$foo->aFuncName}(); // Prints "Inside `aMemberFunc()`" 
?>
```